# Rendering a ReactJS component in memory before placing it in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the concept of a tile in my application.

Tiles are dynamically loaded. They can then be initialized against a DOM element using an `init` method, with the tile taking care of rendering itself.

**features/my-tile/tile.js**

```
import contentsComponentFactory from './components/contents/factory'

const tile = {
  init,
};

// `el` is a DOM element
function init(el) {
  // Render a "contents" ReactJS component (see below) to the DOM - how?
  // Is the following possible?
  el.appendChild(contentsComponentFactory.create({ props }).render());
}

export default tile;
```

A tile has a component `contents` which renders the tile contents to the screen.

**features/my-tile/components/contents/factory.js**

```
const factory = {
  create
};

function create(options) {
  const component = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);

  component.props = options.props;
  component.state = { message: 'This is a tile' };
  component.render = function() {
    return <div>{this.state.message}</div>;
  };

  return component;
}

export default factory;
```

In AngularJS, in `init` I would render the contents in memory and insert the result into the DOM. Can I do this in ReactJS?

I am new to ReactJS and so I may be completely misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to utilize [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) to create the element in memory, and then [ReactDOM.render()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render) in order to insert it into the DOM.

```
const element = React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello, World!');
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('content'));
```

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/PGXwxa?editors=1010

However, `createElement` doesn't return a native DOM element, but rather an instance of [ReactElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-elements). Not sure if this suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a pretty complicated way to do things in AngularJS, maybe you should rethink your design?

It's even worse in React, are you intending on bypassing ReactDOM and inserting it manually?

I'd recommend at least going through the React tutorial before you attempt this.

Comment: I would like to be able to dynamically load a library and have that component take care of rendering itself when asked to do so. In this instance using ReactJS (other components might be Angular or something else). To recap: the page renders. I then load the tile component library over the network. At some later point I need to render this component into the previously rendered DOM. My "solution" above is to render the component in-memory and then insert it into the DOM. What is a better way to do this?

Comment: You appear to be re-implementing the basic functionality of a framework, I strongly recommend you learn how to use React first. Just use ReactDOM.render as it's intended, you can have multiple mount points if required.

Comment: OK thank you. So using `ReactDOM.render` is the way to go for this use case? I am new to React and have since read various introductory texts.